# is AFCI required for 220v CA residential?

Tags: electrical, nec, afci

As I understand it CA now requires AFCI protection for practically all residential outlets.

I'm setting up my theater room and it calls for a 50A 220V NEMA 6-50 outlet for the subwoofer I want but I'm having trouble finding an AFCI breaker in this size.

I know this isn't the right place for product recommendations; I guess I'm more fishing to see if there are exceptions I'm missing?

Comment: Is the circuit run in metal conduit all the way from the panel, and hardwired to the subwoofer?

Comment: Just for reference can we have a link to that sub-woofers product page?  You’ve piqued my interest! I follow theater room trends and I’ve not heard of this.

Comment: @Harper No. It runs to a plug that the subwoofer connects to with a cord.

Comment: @Tyson the Subwoofer is the Paradigm Sub 2. It has better performance when connected with a 220v supply.

Comment: Page 28 of the [manual](https://www.paradigm.com/downloads/MAN0098_EN-FR_090314_ONLINE.pdf) (pdf page 33 of 88) only calls for a 15 amp 240v receptacle (not 50 amp NEMA 6-50).  That makes a lot more sense.....

Comment: @Tyson you're right but I plan to use another 240v device I was hoping to share the circuit.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work that way.  You can't put a bunch of 15A or 20A receptacles on a 50A circuit.  If you need to provision power to multiple devices made to use a 15A or 20A circuit, either run multiple circuits or feed a subpanel.  Yes, all that applies to 240V circuits also. Same rules.

Comment: Harper, 240v outlet adapters are common. I'm not talking about splitting off multiple 20a outlets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### NEC AFCI requirements only apply to 120V, 15/20A circuits

NEC 210.12(A) is clear on this (list omitted):

> **(A) Dwelling Units.** All 120-volt, single-phase, 15- and 20-
>   ampere branch circuits supplying outlets or devices installed in
>   dwelling unit kitchens, family rooms, dining rooms, living
>   rooms, parlors, libraries, dens, bedrooms, sunrooms, recreation
>   rooms, closets, hallways, laundry areas, or similar rooms or
>   areas shall be protected by any of the means described in
>   210.12(A)(1) through (6):

Furthermore, a quick check of the 2016 CEC reveals that it hews to the 2014 NEC language with no state amendments (the quote above is from the 2017 NEC).

Comment: That's interesting as, presumably, there's nothing preventing outlets of higher ratings being installed. Thanks!